# numpy - opposite of array.sum (subtraction?)

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering if there a method that can subtract values? Something similar to `sum`

for Examples

```
> np.array([[10, 2], [1, 2]]).sum() 
15
" imaginary method "
> np.array([[10, 2], [1, 2]]).sub() 
6

# axis = 1
> np.array([[10, 2], [1, 2]]).sum(axis=1)
array([12,  3])
" imaginary method "
> np.array([[10, 2], [1, 2]]).sum(axis=1)
array([8,  -1])

# axis = 0
> np.array([[10, 2], [1, 2]]).sum(axis=0)
array([11,  4])
"imaginary"
> np.array([[10, 2], [1, 2]]).sub(axis=0)
array([9,  0])
```

I am frustrated I cann't find anything in docs (somehow numpy docs are not easy to use if you don't know what you looking for).

thank you.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the axis has length greater than (or less than!) two?

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't have a single array and try to call some sort of `sum`-like method. You'd have two arrays and do `a - b`.

Comment: Multiply the appropriate rows/columns with -1 and then call `sum`.

Comment: There's also [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) that's kind of related and that I occasionally use to do subtraction, but it's probably obfuscating to use that when actually want to do row/col subtraction and not doing finite-differences.

Comment: `diff()` or `subtract()`?

Comment: `subtract` works with two arrays, i need it to work on rows cols or values.  `diff` is what i was looking! go add answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference equivalent of `np.sum()` is `np.diff()`

[Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

Answer (score 1):

`np.sum` is `np.add.reduce`:

```
In [87]: np.add.reduce(arr, axis=0)                                             
Out[87]: array([11,  4])
In [88]: np.add.reduce(arr, axis=1)                                             
Out[88]: array([12,  3])
```

There is a `subtract` `ufunc` too:

```
In [93]: np.subtract.reduce(arr, axis=0)                                        
Out[93]: array([9, 0])
In [94]: np.subtract.reduce(arr, axis=1)                                        
Out[94]: array([ 8, -1])
```

`np.diff` does sliced subtraction:

```
In [97]: np.subtract(arr[:-1,:], arr[1:,:])                                     
Out[97]: array([[9, 0]])
In [98]: np.subtract(arr[:,:-1], arr[:,1:])                                     
Out[98]: 
array([[ 8],
       [-1]])
```

For two elements `diff` and `subtract.reduce` do the same thing.  What's supposed to happen when you have more than 2 rows or columns?

```
In [109]: arr = np.array([[10, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2]])                    
In [110]: arr                                                                   
Out[110]: 
array([[10,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  4],
       [ 0,  1,  2]])
```

`diff` does pair wise subtraction, row 0 from 1, row 1 from 2:

```
In [111]: np.diff(arr, axis=0)                                                  
Out[111]: 
array([[-9,  0,  1],
       [-1, -1, -2]])
```

`subtract.reduce` does a cumulative, which might be easier to follow with the `accumulate` alternative:

```
In [112]: np.subtract.reduce(arr, axis=0)                                       
Out[112]: array([ 9, -1, -3])
In [113]: np.subtract.accumulate(arr, axis=0)                                   
Out[113]: 
array([[10,  2,  3],
       [ 9,  0, -1],
       [ 9, -1, -3]])
```